# Generating Dynamic <li> elements with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm doing a web app for parents and I want to create li elements for each children the parents have, to do so, I have a children database with all the children which use the software, I identify the parent's children by having a column which is filled with the parent email so to get the list of children I query all the children linked to that email.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,nombre, medio, alergias, curso, grupo, plato FROM usuarios WHERE idmail = ? ORDER BY id ASC");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION["email"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $nombre, $medio, $alergias, $curso, $grupo, $plato);
$arrayfinal = array();
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $arrayfinal[] = $id;
    $arrayfinal[] = $nombre;
    $arrayfinal[] = $medio;
    $arrayfinal[] = $alergias;
    $arrayfinal[] = $curso;
    $arrayfinal[] = $grupo;
    $arrayfinal[] = $plato;
}
```

The array "arrayfinal" includes all the family children information.
The list looks like this:[image: list]

The back end looks like this:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-main">
    <li class="nav-active">
        <a href="">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span><? echo $arrayfinal[1]; echo " "; echo $_SESSION["apellido"];?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

That's for each element of the list.

The array I mentioned before looks like this:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Ramon"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Nueces"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "3 ESO"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [7]=>
  int(2)
  [8]=>
  string(6) "Carlos"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "Lactosa"
  [11]=>
  string(6) "2 Batx"
  [12]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [13]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

In this array there's two kids "Carlos" and "Ramon".

Summing up, what I want, is a list that automatically generates elements to the list for each kid the family has using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-main">
<?php
    // connect to your database
    $db_name = 'mydatabase';
    $db_user = 'user';
    $db_pass = 'password';
    $db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8mb4', $db_user, $db_pass);

    // fetch the database data
    $sql = '"SELECT id, nombre, medio, alergias, curso, grupo, plato FROM usuarios WHERE idmail = ? ORDER BY id ASC"';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$_SESSION["email"]]);

    // run through the results and display them
    $results = []; 
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $text = '<li class="nav-active"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>'.$row['nombre'].' '.$_SESSION["apellido"].'</span></a></li>';
        echo("$text\n");
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Please note, that this solution does use PDO instead of mysqli